# Other norms for Lattice reduction techniques (LLL, PSLQ)?

Tags: ds.algorithms

LLL and other lattice reduction techniques (such as PSLQ) try to find a short basis vector relative to the 2-norm, i.e. for a given basis that has $ \varepsilon $ as its shortest vector, $ \varepsilon \in Z^n $, find a short vector s.t. $ b \in Z^n, ||b||_2 < ||c^n \varepsilon||_2 $.

Has there been any work done to find short vectors based on other, potentially higher, norms?  Is this a meaningful question?

Comment: I notice that you've asked the same question on MO:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37563/other-norms-for-lattice-reduction-techniques-lll-pslq 

While crossposting is fine in general, it would be helpful to post on one site and wait for a bit before crossposting, especially since it appears that you've got your answer already on MO. 

Also see http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25/material-to-supplement-the-faq/36#36

Comment: Sorry about this, was a little eager to hear the answer, so I thought I would maximize my chances and cross post.  I'll make sure to give a little time between cross posting next time.

Comment: Answered on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37563/other-norms-for-lattice-reduction-techniques-lll-pslq . I'll keep it here in the hopes of getting more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the specific reference provided by Steve Huntsman in his MO answer leads to the paper

- Oded Regev and Ricky Rosen. *Lattice problems and norm embeddings*, STOC 2006.  doi: [10.1145/1132516.1132581](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1132516.1132581) ([full preprint version](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~odedr/papers/lpnorm.pdf))

This paper presents randomized reductions from the approximation versions of lattice problems in the $\ell_2$ norm to any norm $\ell_p$ where $1 \le p \le \infty$.  The reductions don't quite preserve the approximation ratio, but the loss can be bounded by a factor of $(1+\epsilon)$.  So the $\ell_2$ norm yields in some sense the "easiest" versions of lattice problems.  It is enough to prove hardness of approximation using the $\ell_2$ norm, and hardness of approximation for any other $\ell_p$ norm follows with only a $(1+\epsilon)$ larger approximation factor.

Regev and Rosen then go on to use this to strengthen some existing hardness results.

On the other hand, Chris Peikert showed that lattice problems posed using $\ell_p$ norms are not substantially harder than problems posed in the $\ell_2$ norm.

- Chris Peikert, *Limits on the hardness of lattice problems in $\ell_p$ norms*, Computational Complexity **17** 300–351, 2008.  doi: [10.1007/s00037-008-0251-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00037-008-0251-3) ([full preprint version](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lp_norms.pdf))

So yes, the question is sensible, and it has also essentially been answered.

(Thanks to @user834 for the preprint links.)